# Query reg filter in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-mail

I query emails from my Office 365 mailbox, which are received before a particular date using Microsoft Graph API.

I use following quert : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*email*/mailfolders/Archive/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime lt 2020-04-01

I have manually checked the 'Archive' folder and there are many emails which are received before 2020-04-01. Hence the query should provide output.

My application will automatically run this query every 5 min.

While testing, I found that once the app started it run 12 times (1 hour) and gave correct output, however 13th call onwards, all subsequent calls are giving NULL JSON output.

I get following JSON response:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ns0:RESTOutput xmlns:ns0 = "xxx">
<StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
<msg></msg>
</ns0:RESTOutput>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you cross checked the mailbox whether the archive folder contains the items with the receiveddatetime field against your above query filter (receiveddatetime) when you see NULL?

Comment: Outside of your code, can you repro the issue in Graph Explorer/POSTMAN as well?

Comment: I tried repro the issue, but it works for me. I dont see issue with MS Graph API call.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/142828/query-reg-filter-in-graph-api.html

Comment: Gotcha. Let me move this one to answer then ... So it can be useful to others as well; consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the Graph API call work in MS Graph Explorer and it works without any issue.

API call:

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*email*/mailfolders/Archive/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime lt 2020-04-01
```